# Scoring system in PHP without database

Tags: javascript, php

I want to make a quiz in PHP. 
The answers are chosen from radio buttons. If the user chooses the correct answer his score adds 1 if wrong answer his score is reduced by 1.
Finally I want his score to appear as an alert.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Quiz</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php

$score=0; 

?>

<p><font size="3"> <b>There is 2 multiple choice questions<br />
Every correct answer +1 <br />
Wrong answer -1<br />
Good Luck!</b></font></p></br></br></br>

<table width="300" border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
  <tr>
    <td><p><font size="3"> <b> Question 1:
</b></font></p>
Guess The Star Of The Movie  <font color="red">"The Equalizer"</font><br />
<br />



<input type="radio" name="n1" value="Denzel Washington">Denzel Washington<br>
<input type="radio" name="n1" value="Mark Wahlberg">Mark Wahlberg<br>
<input type="radio" name="n1" value="Jason Statham">Jason Statham<br>
<input type="radio" name="n1" value="Sylvester Stallone">Sylvester Stallone<br>

</form ></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><p><font size="3"> <b> Question 2:
</b></font></p>
Guess The Star Of The Movie  <font color="red">"Game Plan"</font><br />
<br />


<input type="radio" name="n2" value="Vin Diesel">Vin Diesel<br>
<input type="radio" name="n2" value="Dwayne Johnson">Dwayne Johnson<br>
<input type="radio" name="n2" value="Liam Hamworth">Liam Hamworth<br>
<input type="radio" name="n2" value="Adam Sandler">Adam Sandler<br>

</form ></td>
  </tr>

</table>

<?php
$score=0; 

if($n1=="Denzel Washington")
$score = $score+1;
else $score = $score-1;
if($n2=="Dwayne Johnson")
$score = $score+1;
else
$score = $score-1;
?>
<button type="button"  onclick="alert('<?php echo "your score is: ".$score."";  ?> ')">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click the submit button the score is -2 although I have chosen the correct answer

Comment: You can use a session variable to track the score as the user progresses through the quiz.

Comment: The course I'm taking is php and I need to do it in php

Comment: PHP is a perfectly acceptable platform to use for this, course or not.

Comment: It looks like you never opened your form, and depending on your method of submitting for, n1 and n2 are access through $_GET['n1'] or $_POST['n1']

I also see that you have two </form>.  You should have both radios in one form for it to submit together.

Comment: Start by assigning POST variables.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is running unconditionally, EVERY time the page is loaded. That means your "is this answer right" code always declares it wrong. so effectively you've got:

```
$score = 0;
$score = $score - 1; // $n1 is blank, therefore wrong
$score = $score - 1; // $n2 is blank, therefore wrong
```

You should at LEAST be detecting if the form was actually submitted, e.g.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    ... do scoring here ..
}
```

But most of that's irrelevant anyways. You don't even have a `<form>` tag, so there's no way for those input fields to ever submit to anything.

Comment: *Facepalm* - No opening `<form>` tag; how did that one escape me? Exactly what you pointed out, plus OP isn't assigning any `$_POST` variables for the named elements.

Comment: I added <form action="#" method="post"> before the radio buttons
and if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') if($_POST['n1']=="Denzel Washington")
the score is 0